# MySQL connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to build a tool that one step of it is connecting to MySQL database.

Just I am so confused about ODBC. If I want to build a cross platform connector by python, should I use python connector or ODBC connector?

I know JDBC, but ODBC stands for Open Database Connectivity. It looks like more compatible.

Could anyone help me clarify that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has its own [DB API v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) abstraction layer to connect to databases (it serves the same purpose of ODBC or JDBC but for Python). You should use one of the [DB API v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) compliant [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/), [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/) or [PyMySQL](http://www.pymysql.org/) packages to connect to MySQL from Python. All these packages are cross platform and will work on Linux, Windows and MacOS X. [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/), and [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/) are wrappers for libmysql and [PyMySQL](http://www.pymysql.org/) is a pure Python implementation.

Note that there are [DB API v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) implementations (like [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/)) that provide ODBC connectivity, so conceptually you could connect to MySQL via ODBC, but this would have inferior performance than the above mentioned "native" drivers because of the extra abstraction layers.

Comment: Thank you. This clarifies a lot.

Comment: Note that [**MySQL Connector/Python**](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) is available from the MySQL website.